# Dynamically remove and add element to the tab according to parent width on mount and on resize in vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a tab component that displays given items. I want to show a icon when items starting overflow parent and add this items to overlay array,that can be opened by clicking icon. I achieved this on mount but I couldn't it on window resize.I have two array, one for overflown items and the other one for not overflow items. Here is my code. I want to remove and items dynamically on window resize. Here is my current calculate function

```
calculateOverflow() {
      let notOverflowns = [];
      Array.from(this.$refs.tab.$el.children[0].children)
        .filter((item) => item.classList.contains("p-tabmenuitem"))
        .reduce((total, item) => {
          const foundItem = this.items.find(
            (tabItem) => tabItem.label === item.textContent
          );
          if (
            total +
              parseInt(
                window.getComputedStyle(item).getPropertyValue("margin-right")
              ) +
              item.offsetWidth >
            this.$refs.tab.$el.offsetWidth - 55
          ) {
            foundItem && this.overflownItems.push(foundItem);
          } else {
            foundItem && notOverflowns.push(foundItem);
          }
          return (
            total +
            parseInt(
              window.getComputedStyle(item).getPropertyValue("margin-right")
            ) +
            item.offsetWidth
          );
        }, 0);
      this.items = notOverflowns;
    },
```

[image]

Comment: Why not use CSS for this?

Comment: How do I add items to icon menu dynamically ?

Comment: I want to add overflown items to the menu that can be opened by icon click. That's what my problem here